# Connect to many iOS devices over WLAN like multipeer connectivity framework

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity, wifi

I'm searching for something to share data (messages and files) between a teacher device and their students via WLAN, like Multipeer Connectivity Framework but for more devices (assuming that multipeer works up to 8  devices I have a class with 30 students for example) where the teacher device works like a server and the students will find it and connect to it

Could somebody point me in the right direction with this aim?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NSNetService` to publish a service from the teacher device that the pupil devices can connect to. Once connection details are available you can configure socket connection to distribute data.

You could setup the teacher device as an HTTP server (plenty of options on github). You could also modify that to serve other services and potentially use a Bluetooth beacon to publish the service.

There are many options you could go with.